# Consuming JSON - get only string

Tags: spring-mvc

My controller should consume only JSON. The data-structure I'm consuming is unknown, so I'm not able to map it to an object. For now I only want the plain JSON-string and log it. Preferrably only max. 1000 in length accepted, so this can't be used bust memory.

How can I achieve this?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/consume/everything/", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void consumeEverything(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) {
 // ...
 String jsonString = ...;
 LOG.info("jsonString = {}", jsonString);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `@RequestBody` annotation (see [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody)).

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/consume/everything/", 
  method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void consumeEverything(@RequestBody String body) {
```